# React SyntaxError

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error

I am learning React and I have written this code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const element = <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root');
```

However, on executing the Programme, I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

As a can't understand what is the problem in the code. Please do help me out.

Comment: where do you put those imports?

Comment: Can you provide more information? It seems like you are running it in Node but it's a little hard to tell.

Comment: I put the import in App.js

Comment: Looks like your transpiler might not be configured right?

Comment: How can I configure that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you should correct the typo in the word `document`, close your render function and give it the element to render:

```
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I would also add that it is worth starting by setting up your code editor to see such typos.

Answer (score 0):

**You have a missing element here**, so you must need to pass your created `element` const variable to `render()` method as your first argument to render your created element to your `DOM`

So try and review this code.

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Use this reference to know more about [React Rendering Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom)

Comment: On using this code I am getting the same error:                                                 
(node:22004) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
c:\Users\Agniva Roy\master\src\App.js:1
import React from "react";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

From the React docs, [`ReactDOM.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) Render a React element into the DOM in the supplied container, below is the syntax

> ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])

So the two problems in your code are, `document` spelling and the `ReactDOM.render` arguments

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const element = <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Below is the runnable snippet

```js
const element = <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your element to `render()` method as your first argument to render that element and also there is a typo in the word `document` and also your render function is not closed. Try these two things first. For your help =>

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```